# Python Maths Quiz

Tags: python

I'm creating a math quiz with python however I am having a few troubles and I would appreciate it if someone could help me.
I need the program to ask the user 10 questions and then calculate the users score out of 10. However my program fails to do so, instead it asks 12 questions and doesn't calculate the users score.

Here is a copy and paste of my code so far:

```
import random
import operator

def quiz():

    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    name = input("Please enter your name")
    print("Hello", name," Let's begin the quiz!")
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!\n')
            print(score)
            break
        else:
            print('Incorrect!\n')

    return 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)


def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub,
    '*':operator.mul,
    '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,11)
    num2 = random.randint(1,11)   
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer
    print(score)

quiz()
askQuestion()
randomCalc()
```

Comment: As it has been pasted, your code is unusable due to indentation issues.

Comment: *"as part of a school assessment"* - which should be **your own work**, not ours.

Comment: you might be interested in looking at this (surprisingly similar) [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127669/fixing-maths-quiz-in-python/36128216#36128216), and the solution I propose, to grab some ideas

Answer (score 1):

There are some logical and presentational error in your code snippet, The main problem you were facing was getting 12 questions instead of 10, That was because you were calling the `askQuestion()` and `randomCalc()` at the end of the code whilst calling them from inside the `quiz()` function itself. Another issue was using a `break` statement inside your `for` loop, I guess you confused `continue` and `break` statement, `break` is used to exit the loop, But in case of Python `for` loop, you don't need any `break/continue` construct. The furnished code may look like

```
import random
import operator

def quiz():

    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    name = input("Please enter your name")
    print("Hello", name," Let's begin the quiz!")
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!')
            print "Score",(score),"\n"
        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
            print "Score",(score), "\n"

    print 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)


def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub,
    '*':operator.mul,
    '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,11)
    num2 = random.randint(1,11)   
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer

quiz()
#askQuestion()
#randomCalc()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be off-the-mark since (at the time of writing this) your indentation didn't come through properly, but I believe you need to change this:

```
quiz()
askQuestion()
randomCalc()
```

To this:

```
print(quiz())
```

As you have it now, "Your score was..." never gets printed because you `return` that string at the end of `quiz`, but you never do anything with the result. And you're getting 12 questions asked instead of 10 because you're unnecessarily calling `askQuestion` and `randomCalc` after calling `quiz`.

Comment: Thank you for responding however when I do what you told me to do them score isn't correct. as soon as I get an answer correct it goes straight to the score without asking and further questions. What's the problem?

Comment: I can't tell until you edit your post with the correct indentation.

Comment: anmol suggested deleting the `break`, have you tried that?

Comment: sorry I seemed to have missed anmol's suggestion let me try that now

Comment: Thank You so much Anmol and Kevin my code is now working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things in the outputs, you should use .format for vaiables instead of anything else.

It should be working now...

```
import random
import operator

    def quiz():

    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    name = input("Please enter your name\n")
    print("Hello", name,"\n Let's begin the quiz!")
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
            score = score + 1
            print('Correct!')
            print ("Score is {}".format(score))
        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
            print ("Score is {}".format(score))

     print("{}, your score was {}/10".format(name, score))


def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub,
    '*':operator.mul,
    '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,11)
    num2 = random.randint(1,11)   
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer

quiz()
#askQuestion()
#randomCalc()
```

Comment: Edit: at the end it says your name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple-to-understand Maths quiz. Although I'm a beginner (and 14yo), I created this quiz which means you should be able to understand it.
This quiz also features a countdown (optional) which I added to make the quiz slightly more interesting and it rejects any non-integer value:)

```
from random import randint 
import time
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
print("Hello %s, Let's begin the quiz!" % name)

time.sleep(3)
for x in range(0,3):
    print(3 - x)
    time.sleep(1)
print("GO!\n")

start_time = time.time()
score = 0

#0,10 is the number of questions you want.
for x in range(0, 10):
    #30,50 are values which decides the range of the two numbers. eg. 39,44
    y = randint(30,50)
    z = randint(30,50)

    while True:
        try:
            ans = int(input("Question %s: What is %s + %s = " % (x + 1, y, z)))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't get that.")
            continue
        else:
            break

    if y + z == ans:
        score = score + 1
        print("Correct\n")
    else:
        print("Wrong\n")

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

print("\n\n%s, you scored %s/10!\nYou took %ss to complete the quiz! " % (name,score,round(elapsed_time)))
```